# How can I find if Windows is running on a VM or on a physical machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I have a Windows server where we run some of the project managements services. I usually [remote desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) into it to manage the service.

The service has become really slow and the documentation says that it’s not advisable to run the service on a [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

How do I find out if the Windows install is running on a VM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a look through [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager). You'll most likely have quite a few VMware of virtual drivers that you wouldn't get on a physical machine.

Also you could type `systeminfo` into a CMD window and if it says *"System Manufacturer: VMware, Inc."* or similar instead of Microsoft Windows then you'll be able to work out of the setup_ is virtual or not.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, click Start → write *msinfo32* → press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

System manufacturer info will display "VMware. Inc" if it is a VMware VM. Probably other VM platforms like [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), etc. will also fill this information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@echo off
systeminfo > temp.txt
findstr /e "System Model:              Virtual Machine" temp.txt
del temp.txt
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Physical machine

) else (
    echo Virtual machine
)
```

Comment: Does not work, at least with VMWare. It has `System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform` instead.